# List needs to be clickable and bring in new content. Using iframes. Is there a better way

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have it working... Kind of. The content loads into the DIV but it is static. The content being pulled in is using the smoothDicScroll library. It works with an iframe but not with this. Here is the tweaked code I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
    function loadcontent (url) {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").load(url) ;
    };
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="scroll-list">
    <ul id="site-nav">
        <li> <a href="javascript:loadcontent('iframeinsertA.html', 'makeMeScrollable')"> This link </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="javascript:loadcontent('iframeinsertB.html', 'makeMeScrollable')"> That link </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="scroll-container">
       <div id="makeMeScrollable">
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, you can load content into a `Div`, though it needs a little jquery effort as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a JS function like ,

```
 function Loadcontent (url) {
  $("#makeMeScrollable").load(url , new function (){ alert ('Content loaded')}) ;
 }
```

and call it like

```
 <li> <a href="javascript: LoadContent('iframeinsertS.html');return false;" >That link</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm at work now but I will try your suggestions when I get a chance.

Comment: OK. Reading thru this answer more thoroughly. I see that you have the JS function and you are calling it thru the link. How do I insert it in the page though?

Comment: You don't need to insert it into the page, jquery shall do it for you in load function. For details http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Furqan's answer about the js implementation is right.

About the li breaking in new line, it's the normal behavior from a . If you want the links to be in the same line, you should change CSS.
Something like:

```
ul li {
float: left; clear: none; width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm at work now but I will try your suggestions when I get a chance.

Comment: Whoops, hit return too soon. About the li item. By break, I meant that it all ran together once I put the 'a' in. Before that it all worked fine.